# How to rearrange matrices?

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I need to create a function, that will rearrange any square matrix based on the values in the matrix.

So if I have matrix like this:

```r
M <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
M
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    5    9   13
#> [2,]    2    6   10   14
#> [3,]    3    7   11   15
#> [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

After rearrangement it needs to look like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    6   10
[2,]    2    5    9   13
[3,]    4    8   12   15
[4,]    7   11   14   16
```

So it is sorted from lowest (left upper corner) to highest (right lower corner), but the numbers are sorted on diagonal (is that the right word?) not in rows or columns.

I know how to to this "manually", but I can't figure out any rules that this rearrangement operates by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function `columns_to_diagonals` in base R that ought to do what you're after. It uses `split` and `unsplit` with the appropriate factors.

```r
columns_to_diagonals <- function(M) {
  n <- ncol(M)
  f <- matrix(rep(1:(2*n-1), c(1:n, (n-1):1)), ncol = n)
  m <- split(M, f)
  d <- row(M) + col(M)
  matrix(unsplit(m, d), ncol = n)
}
```

First, we may test this on your original case:

```r
M <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
columns_to_diagonals(M)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    3    6   10
#> [2,]    2    5    9   13
#> [3,]    4    8   12   15
#> [4,]    7   11   14   16
```

And then a larger, randomly permutated matrix, to check that this looks fine as well:

```r
M <- matrix(sample(1:25), ncol = 5)
M
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    4   15   12   10   21
#> [2,]   19    7    5   23    6
#> [3,]    9   17    2    8    1
#> [4,]    3   11   16   25   14
#> [5,]   22   18   20   13   24
columns_to_diagonals(M)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    4    9   15   18   20
#> [2,]   19   22   11   16   25
#> [3,]    3   17    2    8    6
#> [4,]    7    5   23   21   14
#> [5,]   12   10   13    1   24
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your promt response! I think I was able to understand your approach :D. And here I was sitting, thinking how to change each individual number :D. I made slight change to the code so that it sorts from lowest to highest:      `s <- matrix(sort(M),n) #added this in, so that I get sorted matrix
... d <- row(s) + col(s)-1 #added -1 so that the coeficients match with f/m - it works without it

Answer (score 9):

**1)** `row(m) + col(m)` is constant along reverse diagonals so:

```
M <- replace(m, order(row(m) + col(m)), m)
```

gving:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    6   10
[2,]    2    5    9   13
[3,]    4    8   12   15
[4,]    7   11   14   16
```

It is not clear whether sorted on the diagonal means just that they are unravelled from the storage order onto the reverse diagonals or that they are actually sorted after that within each reverse diagonal. In the example in the question the two interpretations give the same answer; however, if you did wish to sort the result within reverse diagonal afterwards using different data then apply this:

```
ave(M, row(M) + col(M), FUN = sort)
```

**2)** A longer version:

```
M2 <- matrix(m[order(unlist(tapply(seq_along(m), row(m) + col(m), c)))], nrow(m))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not able to wrap my head around the inner workings of your code. For instance how to add sorting element, so that the numbers are always sorted from lowest to highest in ascending order along the diagonals. Thank you

Comment: Have simplified it.

Comment: Regarding sorting, have expanded the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are extremely helpful!!